JWT: to sign the claims with public key or private key, which way to go?
I am looking into sign JWT token with secret key (pem).
I did some investigation and it seems JWT is suppose to utilize private key to sign the claim.
What if can I sign the JWT claims with public key instead?
There's similar question here can json web token sign with public key, but without accepted answer.
Could someone explain in depth, why signing with private key is preferred?
Thanks.
I've tried to google, and found no explicit example for signing JWT claim with public key.

The linked question has comments and answers, to sum it up, its pointless to "sign" something using a public key. You gain nothing by "verifying" a signature literally anyone can generate,

Thanks for the prompt reply, the explanation makes sense.

The purpose of signing a jwt is to prove that you and no one else issued that tokens. In order to prove this, you have to use a key, that only you posess. And as the name suggests, that's not the case with a public key.

@derpirscher Thank you, in that case, I'll sign the claims with private key.

I did more investigation, tried with signing with public key.
Here's the conclusion:
To sign with public key is:

Theoretically inapplicable/inappropriate
And also cannot be achieved by code, as the ,NET framework is expecting private key.

Refer to details below:
GitHub issue 251
Thanks everyone for clarifying this.
